# is this optimal?

Tags: sql, oracle

i mean using variables to refer to the table in the select but not in the where section:

```
SELECT TPJ.A,
       TPJ.B,
       TPJ.C,
       TPJ.D
  FROM SCHEMA.TABLE TPJ
 WHERE A = 'V1'
   AND B = 'V2'
   AND C = 'V3';
```

Comment: Inconsistency is always sub-optimal.

Comment: `tpj` isn't a variable, it's a table alias. (And it's *'select **list**'*, and *'where **clause**'*.)

Comment: thank you @WilliamRobertson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advise you to *always* qualify column references with the table alias.  So, I think this:

```
SELECT t.A, t.B, t.C, t.D
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE t
WHERE t.A = 'V1' AND
      t.B = 'V2' AND
      t.C = 'V3';
```

I freely admit that it makes little difference for a query with one table reference.  However, it is not uncommon for me to take one query and then make it more complicated.  That process is simpler starting with fully qualified column names.

Comment: Couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 1):

Your query isn't optimal from a stylistic point of view, because you define a table alias but then don't consistently use it everywhere.  Since your query is against a single table, you don't even need an alias, and I would not use one:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE
WHERE
    A = 'V1' AND
    B = 'V2' AND
    C = 'V3';
```

That being said, what you wrote should still run, because Oracle should be able to resolve either `A` or `TPJ.A`.

Comment: and if it were used on a "join" ? then the alias would be useful, right?

Comment: @CarlosCruzAcuña Yes, but not necessarily due to the join, but rather due to that there would then be 2 or more tables being referenced in your query, and using aliases would make that query easier to read.

Comment: My own *best practice* says "always use table alias". P.S. Ah, now I saw - Gordon says that too :)